# Why are my D3 force layout diagram lines extending into circles?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

It am not doing anything odd here.  But I can't seem to get them to match up with the outer edge of the circle.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
        // Create Nodes
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("g")
        //.group(d.group)
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("mouseover", nodeMouseover)
        .on("mouseout", nodeMouseout)
        .call(force.drag);

    // Append circles to Nodes
    var circle = node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 8)
        .style("stroke", function (d) { return d.BaseColor; })
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.ID; })
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(force.links())
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link arrow")

    // Draw lines for Links between Nodes
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(force.links())
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link arrow")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In svg the latest object created goes front, that's why you usually create the links before the nodes. Links are by default attached to the center of nodes. You can see this for exemple if you change the opacity of a node for it to be slightly transparent.

```
// Draw lines for Links between Nodes
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(force.links())
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link arrow")

// Create Nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("g")
    //.group(d.group)
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("mouseover", nodeMouseover)
    .on("mouseout", nodeMouseout)
    .call(force.drag);

// Append circles to Nodes
var circle = node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .style("stroke", function (d) { return d.BaseColor; })
    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.ID; })
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up; The light bulb went on right before I saw your post.